# Any public dataset of U.S Highways and on and off ramps?

Tags: openstreetmap, data, united-states

I am working on a student project in data engineering and need a database with U.S. Highways and their on and off ramps. I took a look at OpenStreetMap and couldn't figure out if the information I was looking for was there.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to take OSM-Datas, I can recommend: http://download.geofabrik.de/north-america.html. When opening the data only import polyline file. To only have highways and on/off ramps search the attribute table.

A detailed feature list of osm attributes can be found on: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Map_Features

So do (just an example, dunno the right feature names, that you have to look up): 
add to selection "type" = 'highway' 
add to selection "type" = 'highway_ramp' 
--> save only selected as new file

Comment: You should look for "link-roads": http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Map_Features#Link_roads